# react not allowing two css : focus selectors on one jsx element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, focus

i have a react script with a particular element that i would like to have more than one :focus-within selector for in css, however for some reason when i focus on the element only one of the focus selecctors are expressed the `dropdown` one,
this is the code
react js:

```
return (
    <div>
      <div className="blind"></div>
      <div className="menufocus" tabIndex={0}>
        <div className="menuicon">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solid("bars")} />
        </div>
        <div className="dropdown">
          <div className="dropitem">HOME</div>
          <div className="dropitem">ABOUT</div>
          <div className="dropitem">NEWS</div>
          <div className="dropitem">ICONHOLDERS</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

css:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 1vh;
  transition: max-height 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  color: white;
}

.blind {
  z-index: 1001;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  display: none;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.menufocus {
  z-index: 1002;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

.menufocus:focus-within .dropdown {
  max-height: 18vh;
}
.menufocus:focus-within .blind {
  display: block;
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within):

> The :focus-within CSS pseudo-class matches an element if the element
> or any of its descendants are focused. In other words, it represents
> an element that is itself matched by the :focus pseudo-class or has a
> descendant that is matched by :focus. (This includes descendants in
> shadow trees.)

To sum up, `.menufocus` node is looking ONLY for its children to be focused, and your `.blind` is a signing to it. Just make it to be a child of the `.menufocus`.

Comment: Yes but when the user is trying to click off the .menufocus they won't be able to considering the .blind spans the entire screen so they will be permanently stuck on the menu

Comment: Sorry, I did not get completely what to you want to achieve. It may be useful to have some screenshots with explanations, or a live code example instead of just bare code, because the problem may be in the chosen approach. Anyway, your current CSS behaves as it should be

Comment: I'm currently away from my workstation but I will send the relevant information in around an hour, sorry to keep you waiting

Answer (score -1):

ok im back,
[the menu closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzJKV.png)
then when you focus on the burger(the 3 bars) the result should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEBKS.png) with the blur being evident in the background

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).